# How to set DOCKER_HOST with fixed ip address or system variable?

Tags: eclipse, docker, minikube

I am using eclipse docker tooling perspective to handle minikube docker repository on windows 10. The installation and configuration of minikube are successful.

```
> minikube docker-env
$Env:DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY = "1"
$Env:DOCKER_HOST = "tcp://172.17.63.134:2376"
$Env:DOCKER_CERT_PATH = "C:\Users\joseph\.minikube\certs"
$Env:MINIKUBE_ACTIVE_DOCKERD = "minikube"
# To point your shell to minikube's docker-daemon, run:
# & minikube -p minikube docker-env | Invoke-Expression
```

When managing docker images, I use docker explorer of docker tooling perspective. And below image is the the Docker Connection Dialog

[image]

[Test Connection] is successful and the connection throws no errors. But the problem is the DOCKER_HOST of minikube is variable. The DOCKER_HOST is not fixed and is changeable whenever minikube is started. I want to know how to fix the DOCKER_HOST ip address when minikube is started or the system variable of DOCKER_HOST with which I can set the value of docker tcp connection URI of eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reproduced your problem using the following steps:

- `minikube start --vm-driver=xhyve`
- `minikube ip`  (note the IP address)
- `minikube stop`
- `minikube delete`
- `minikube start --vm-driver=xhyve`
- `minikube ip`  (IP address has changed)

After digging around I understood that at the moment there is no support for predictable IP's across restarts.

There is an open issue for this and you can follow it [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/951).